# Python FTP query

Tags: python, ftp

I am trying to implement FTP download from a UNIX server into a windows box. I have got this far(code below) , but get an error specifying a `file` object is required but `str`
is passed

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ftplib
filename = "filename"
ftp = ftplib.FTP("xx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
ftp.login("uid", "psw")
ftp.cwd("/my/location")
print filename
ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, file.write)
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FTP.py", line 10, in <module>
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, file.write)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ftplib.py", line 399, in retrbinary
    callback(data)
TypeError: descriptor 'write' requires a 'file' object but received a 'str'
```

Can anyone advise how to sort this. Also if possible where can I get some sample examples to learn Python FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open a local file to write to.

Change

```
ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, file.write)
```

to

```
ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, open(filename, 'wb').write)
```

Comment: It did run succesfully. I am not sure where the file goes though ? Where did it get downloaded? Or did it at all ?

Comment: @misguided: That's controlled by the `filename` argument to `open`. If there's no path, the file will be created in the script's current working directory.

Comment: so how do I write the file into my local windows system ? The scripts is being run on a unix server .

Answer (score 0):

```
ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, open('myoutputfile.txt', 'wb').write)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the file you are going to write to using `with open`. Supposing you are reading from file `server_filename` and writing to the file `local_filename`:

```
with open(local_filename, 'wb') as opened_file:
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % server_filename, opened_file.write)
```